# Counting from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, join, count

I have 2 tables.

A

```
Id  Name
1    ab
2    cd
3    eg
4    fg
```

B

```
FkID 
1
2
2
1
1
2
4
```

Since 3 is not there in B in the FKID column. I need to find the count in table A which has value in table B which have a value in FKID also.
So th total count should be 3. In my query, I am getting 7 after the left join.

Comment: Use count(distinct FkID) with an inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a join, you can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select count(*) from a
where exists (
  select 1 from b
  where b.fkid = a.id
)
```

I believe `EXISTS` is more efficient than a join, but if you need a join then it has to be an `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
select count(distinct a.id)
from a inner join b
on b.fkid = a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `COUNT(DISTINCT B.FkId)` the result can be achiveable. The COUNT is not considering the `NULL` values, so the following query will work.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.FkId) AS Occurence
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.FkId = A.Id;
```

or it can be achiveable with `INNER JOIN` too

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.FkId) AS Occurence
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.FkId = A.Id;
```

Demo with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE  (Id INT, [Name] VARCHAR (2));

INSERT INTO @TableA (Id, [Name]) VALUES
(1, 'ab'),
(2, 'cd'),
(3, 'eg'),
(4, 'fg');

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (FkId INT);

INSERT INTO @TableB (FkId) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(2),
(1),
(1),
(2),
(4);

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.FkId) AS Occurence
FROM @TableA A
LEFT JOIN @TableB B ON B.FkId = A.Id
```

Comment: Why not use an inner join? You have logically done that by counting B.FkID.

Comment: @SeanLange `INNER JOIN` also works, since OP said using `LEFT JOIN` he/she get 7 (wrong result), so given the result with `LEFT JOIN`. Here `COUNT` will not include the `NULL` so this solution also works

Comment: Sure it works, but if this is a large dataset this is not as efficient as an inner join.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, valid point. `left join` is coming in to picture due to OP's comments in the post.